# Setting up Google Analytics iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup Google analytics for my app but I do not know how to make a distinction between Production and Testing environments. I also do not how to track a specific user. Are these points even possible?

How I'm currently able to measure if ANYONE lands on a screen in ANY environment is through the following code:

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "LandingViewController")

    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

What I want to do is: 
- post a user id along with the information logged by GA 
- post the APIs base URL that the environment is using back to GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to send the user id and the api base URL as custom dimensions. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

```
tracker.set(GAIFields.customDimensionForIndex(1), value: userId)
tracker.set(GAIFields.customDimensionForIndex(2), value: baseURL)
```

Another way to distinguish between Production and Testing is to set up an entirely separate tracking id for Testing - as mentioned by Marta

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute trackingId from GAI in order to difference environments. 
Using analytics.google.com you need to create a project and inside it you must create two properties. One for test environment and another for production. You will use these ids to difference it.

To post the userId:

```
 let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent( 
            withCategory: "SomeCategory",
            action: "SomeAction",
            label: "someLabel",
            value: userId).build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that this code creates and sends an "Event", which is different from the "Screen View" that the OP is sending.